# .NET TextBox TextArea String prepopulate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

This works:

```
@Html.TextBox("body", ViewData["body"], new { @class = "form-control" })
```

though this:

```
@Html.TextArea("body", ViewData["body"], new { @class = "form-control" })
```

returns this error:

> CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Obviously its something to do with the text area but why?

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions.textarea(v=vs.118).aspx) to see what the parameters of `Html.TextArea()` are?  I imagine you would start there before asking all of us to do that for you...

Comment: See [HtmlHelper.TextArea Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538178(v=vs.111).aspx) vs [HtmlHelper.TextBox Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548042(v=vs.111).aspx) - looks pretty obvious what's happening

Comment: Also, Intellisense is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewData is a collection of objects. The textarea overload requires a string. If your view data item is a string, then convert it to a string.

```
@Html.TextArea("body", ViewData["body"].ToString(), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Or it it were a complex object, then cast to the object and ref the required property.. Again convert to string is not a string already.

```
@Html.TextArea("body", ((MyObject)ViewData["body"]).MyProperty.ToString(), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `TextArea` overload takes the string value as the second parameter.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextArea(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    string value,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

The expression `ViewData["body"]` returns an `object`, not a string. You need to explicitly cast `ViewData["body"]` to a string and pass that as the parameter. You can do a safe cast using `as`  operator.

```
@Html.TextArea("body",ViewData["body"] as string, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It works for `TextBox` helper because the `TextBox` overload takes an `object` type for the value parameter.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    object value,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
)
```